# Obtener Lista de Roles de la tabla AspNetRoles en MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Quiero que en el registro que viene por defecto al crear un proyecto en MVC5, debajo de repetir contraseña poner una lista de selección (`ComboBox`) donde me muestre el listado de los roles que existen en la tabla `AspNetRoles` que crea por defecto el Visual Studio.

He tenido problemas al obtener el listado de los `AspNetRoles`, ya que no sé cuál es el contexto que Utiliza el `Idendity`, y tampoco se crear con exactitud el `select`.

> Solo necesito saber como obtener el listado en el controlador y como
>   pasarlo a la vista, **el `Insert` no lo necesito.**

Mi Controlador:

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}
```

Mi Vista:

```
@model StyleTest.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registrarse";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Cree una cuenta nueva.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrarse" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Mi conexión en el web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=StyleTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="StyleTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Contexto.StyleTest.csdl|res://*/Contexto.StyleTest.ssdl|res://*/Contexto.StyleTest.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=StyleTest;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Uso MVC5 con Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero se debe instanciar el contexto:

```
ApplicationDbContext userContext;
```

Después agregar esto en el `register` o donde necesites:

```
userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
var roles = userContext.Roles.ToList();
ViewBag.roles = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name");
```

Por último en tu vista debes poner lo siguiente para que refleje los datos que necesitas:

```
@Html.DropDownList("roles", ViewBag.roles as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Eso es todo.

Answer (score 3):

Nunca es mala idea leer la documentación relativa a Identity y de cómo funciona internamente. Con esto sabrías que Identity tiene su propio context relativo a la **aplicación (ApplicationDbContext)**. De hecho, si habilitas migraciones en un proyecto recién generado por VS verás que pide especificar a qué DbContext estás apuntando dicha migración (esto ya que puedes "extender" las propiedades de IdentityModels). En la [documentación oficial](https://www.asp.net/identity) podrás ver las razones y el por qué de todo esto.

Primero, dentro de tu controlador debes hacer ciertas definiciones:

```
ApplicationDbContext userContext;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
get
    {
        return _userManager ??
 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

public MiControladorController()
    {
        userContext = new ApplicationDbContext(); 
    }
```

Con esto asignas el `ApplicationDbContext()` a una variable `userContext`, ¿qué logras con esto?... acceder a la API de Identity como si fuera un DbContext común y corriente. Podrás ver las clases Roles, Users, etc. y hacer las consultas vía LINQ que estimes convenientes (entre ellas asignas a un enumerable los roles para pasarlas a tu SelectList).

Sería algo así (obtengo roles/usuarios y usuario en particular):

```
var roles = context.Roles.Include(r => r.Users).OrderBy(r => r.Name).AsQueryable();
var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
```

Luego para pasar a SelectList (en este caso vía ViewBag, usa lo que quieras, puedes incluso enviar estos datos en JSON para explotarlos en un front en JS):

```
ViewBag.RolesDDL = new SelectList(roles, "Id", "Name");
```

El select que asignes a ese ViewBag vía Razor tendrá como `value` el ID del rol y como `option` el nombre del rol.

En tu método de POST para el registro (que tendrás que usar un viewModel sí o sí para poder agregar este nuevo campo de forma correcta) puedes asignar el rol de la siguiente forma:

```
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, nombreRol);
```

Debes usar `UserManager`para poder obtener el ID del usuario, en la implementación inicial ya está inicializado por lo que puedes usarlos directamente.

Yo he creado un paquete NuGet que genera un controlador y vistas con todo lo necesario para la creación, asignación, edición y borrado de roles a diferentes usuarios. Es para MVC5 y las vistas están para Bootstrap:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ManageUsersProsmart/

Lo instalas y listo, también te puede servir de ejemplo. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, solo necesito obtener la lista de roles en el Text el nombre del rol, y en el value el id del rol, lo del insert me queda mas facil hacerlo de otra manera